# Wireless Oneway Broadcast Feasibility

Tags: networking, udp, wireless, adhoc

I am planning on a small project and need help regarding its feasibility.

I have a few wireless mobile devices (could be phones and laptops) which **periodically broadcast packets and also each device listens for other broadcasts**. Any device in range should receive the broadcasted data (no need to reply or ackwnoledge).

1. To perform this can I just send UDP packets with address 255.255.255.255, I heard this was deprecated. If so how do I achieve this? There is no underlying network topology so I cannot rely on multicast or is there a way?
2. If there are 100 such devices, all in wireless range, each 1 performing a periodic broadcast and receive, will it work? will there be too many collisions ? and become infeasible. Each device receiving 70% of the packets is a good performance according to me.

Thank You

Comment: What wireless spec are you working with?

Comment: A standard 802.11 WiFi that comes with laptops and smart phones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it doesn't work this way.

You won't be able to send IP-layer broadcast packets until you have associated with an access point.  Once association has been made, only devices associated with the same AP (and other devices bridged to the IP over its wired interface) will see your broadcasts.  The same goes for layer 2 broadcasts as well.

What you need is to get at a lower layer.  Unfortunately, each WiFi adapter has different methods for doing this, and for many, it isn't even possible.  I'm afraid what you are attempting will not work.

Comment: But how do people working on ad-hoc networks and pervasive computing work without an access point? and how is my AP working, all its doing is broadcasting data (connection information), which my mobile device can listen ? All I want to perform is such a broadcast from mobile devices (let me not be specific about WiFi, UDP, etc... could be any mode of wireless) is there a way ?

Comment: Ad-hoc mode is a specifically defined mode provided by 802.11.  You are still "associated" with an SSID, it just so happens that there is no AP.  Your mobile device hears your AP because it is "associated" with it.  Once association happens, the device then passes the network data to the upper layers.  What you are asking requires monitor mode on the receiving end, and a device that will send raw data on the transmitting end.  The only way I see this working is with devices that are associated on the same network.  Then, regular broadcasts will function.

Comment: Thank you very much. Consider this case, When I take my laptop to a WiFi hotspot, "the laptop can receive the data broadcasted from the AP" and that data shows up on my connection manager, I can then choose to connect (Note my laptop is not associated with the AP, its just in range). Similarly when 2 ad-hoc devices are in range there should  be some way of telling that a device is in range (or else how will it get the SSID of the other intially). So there is some way of receieving samll amount of data by just being in range and still not "associated" to each other.

Comment: Right, but these are all 802.11 management frames.  The adapter/driver handle all of this.  These low-level methods are not exposed to you as a developer.  In some rare cases, they are, but it is a proprietary API for each driver/hardware.  Generally, you can't just transmit any old data with off-the-shelf hardware, as it's internal firmware is handling 802.11.  You can buy specialized hardware for this, and with some drivers (usually under Linux) you can even send such packets, but there is no standard.  Read up on monitor mode to get an idea of what you need to do just on the receiving end.

Comment: I'll look into it and try to come up with alternatives. Thanks dude for all the fast reply and helping me understand the concept.